# Modifying array with For loop, changes don't persist

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net

Curious issue I am experiencing.

I iterate through an array that was created from a string split. On iteration, I make modifications to the items in the array. (Add characters to the item (string, in this regard)

The changes are affected IN the for loop, but when using this array directly after the for loop, the changes seems to be "dropped", and the original array, as before the changes, is used.

It is probably a byRef, byVal issue... but I am not specifically passing it anywhere.

Maybe someone can shed some light on this behavior. I have since built a list inside the for loop, and add to it as I make the string changes. I then use the list in my select statement. This works, but I am curious as to why the array drops its changes.

Regards

```
Dim descriptionSplit() As String
descriptionSplit = Split(unit.itemDescription, "[")

'add the cut "[" back to the strings . "[" was cut from the strings when it was split  ON "["
For Each splitSection As String In descriptionSplit.
'add back the '[' char
splitSection = "[" & splitSection
Debug.Print(splitSection)
Next

'look for and find TAGS
For Each splitSection As String In descriptionSplit
Select Case True
'Look for #UNIT# TAG

'######## HERE, the array has reverted to the original copy....
Case splitSection.Contains("[U]")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `For Each`, the `splitSection` variable is not a reference to an array item, but a copy of the array item. Thus the array itself is never changed.

Iterate the array using `For` and an index variable and access the array directly to make changes.

I'm not too up to date on my Visual Basic, but in C# it should somewhat like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < descriptionSplit.Length; i++)
    descriptionSplit[i] = "[" + descriptionSplit[i];
```

---

I'll shamelessly nick the code that James posted and also post it here for the sake of completeness and to conceal my inability to write VB.NET from memory :-)

```
For index As Integer = 0 To descriptionSplit.Length-1
    descriptionSplit(index) = "[" & descriptionSplit(index)
Next
```

Comment: Does this apply ONLY to arrays? Or to any object used in a For Each loop? I am sure I have made changes to objects using for each before?

Comment: @LouisvanTonder as I stated in my answer, when using `For Each` with *value* types (e.g. `String`/`Integer` etc.) the item is a copy, when using reference types you get the original reference.

Comment: As @James is saying, this is only a problem for array of *value types*. If, for example, you have an array of objects, this is not a problem, because objects are not copied, but referenced.

Comment: Just to be extra clear (and correct me if I'm wrong), but it will only work for modifying objects, like `for each item in array item.value = "new value"` will modify the object in the array but `for each item in array item = new Object()` will still not change the array, correct?

Comment: That should be correct. As opposed to `array(i) = new Object()`, which again will change the array itself.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't actually modifying the array at all here, when you do a `For Each` on a value type you get a *copy* of each item therefore

```
splitSection = "[" & splitSection
```

Is only applicable within the context of the loop, those changes will not be reflected in the array.

If your goal is to modify the items as you process them then you should use a basic `for` loop where you can index into the array e.g.

```
For index As Integer = 0 To descriptionSplit.Length-1
    descriptionSplit(index) = "[" & descriptionSplit(index)
Next
```

Comment: Thanks, I will be accepting the other answer due to its addition of a solution. Thank you for this reply.

Comment: @LouisvanTonder my answer has a solution - and it's in the correct language.

Comment: Sorry, it did not when I posted my comments, or did I miss it?

Comment: @James Your code is not correct. It should read `descriptionSplit(index) = "[" & item`

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Good spot, had an extra `item` in there, updated. Was actually able to get rid of the temp variable as well given the item is only ever needed once.

Answer (score 1):

You never change your array. What you do is the following:

You assign a *new value*  to your loop variable.

That's all. This doesn't change the value inside your array.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of this code:

```
For Each splitSection As String In descriptionSplit
Select Case True
 ...
```

Your `splitSection` becomes a string of the `descriptionSplit`, and that split array is array of *original*  strings.

for you need to change array of **original** split.

I'm not an expert in `VB`, but considering that you wrote in tags `C#`:

```
for(var i=0; i< descriptionSplit.Length; i++) {
    descriptionSplit[i] = "[" + descriptionSplit[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, from what I've seen so far:

You're only assigning a new reference to your variable `splitSection`, which only exists within the loop's scope - so the reference within the array will never change.

Solution:

```
Dim descriptionSplit() As String
descriptionSplit = Split(unit.itemDescription, "[")

For i As Integer = 0 To descriptionSplit.Length - 1 
    descriptionSplit(i) = "[" & descriptionSplit(i)
Next
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This won't even compile, `splitSelection` & `splitSection` are never defined.